# How to import from other scripts in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I created the following two scripts in a brand new empty folder called `F:\python\hello_world`, using *Visual Studio Code*:

The first is `my_function.py`:

```
def hello() -> str:
    return "Hello, World"
```

The second is `my_app.py`:

```
from my_function import hello

print(hello())
```

When I run this from Visual Studio Code, I get an error saying I can't import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/python/hello_world/my_app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_function import hello
ImportError: cannot import name 'hello' from 'my_function' (f:\python\hello_world\my_function.py)
```

Any clue? I've recently switched from using PyCharm to using VSCode, and I can't quite seem to get started...

### New Development

It turns out that, unlike my toy example (which works fine as soon as I add `__init__.py` to the project's folder), I was trying to run code from within a subfolder of the project. That's a VSCode no-no.

Comment: Are your files in one same directory?

Comment: Yes, everything is sitting in a folder called `F:\python\hello_world`

Comment: So, any previous project you've written in Pycharm just doesn't work when you run it in vscode? What happens when you just use the terminal to run `python my_app.py`? Because that's literally all that vscode does

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't know because I've switched jobs. Old shop used PyCharm and new shop uses VSCode.

Comment: Ultimately the IDE doesn't matter. Where the terminal opens its working directory does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), it said

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories
> containing the file as packages.

But without it, your code still works well in my VS Code. You may try resetting VS Code by deleting folders `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode` then see if the error goes away.

Comment: The addition of `__init__.py` did make my problem go away, thank you.  As for my _in real life_ problem, the solution was to just reorganise my project in such a way that I'm always running code from the root folder.

Comment: @lebelinoz. That's okay. Happy Coding:)